# Working on a command line interpreter and can't get the && and || to work correctly

Tags: c, command-line-interface

While trying to create a very basic command line interpreter I have come across a section I can't seem to figure out. While I am checking the token for the required delimeters I can't seem to correctly enable the && and || functions. Listed below is the loop that inserts the args and then created the process.

I am just focusing on the && at the moment and plan to use that implementation to help with the || function. Can you guys please take a look and help point me into the right direction?

Side note: this is also my first time writing a program in C, so there might be some errors in the code because of that.

This is a homework problem.

Thanks

Updated with full program code that I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define ARG_SIZE 1<<16
#define MAXLINE 100

char *args[ARG_SIZE];
int place = 0;
int return_status;

void insert( char *token ){
    args[ place ] = token;
    place++;
}

void create() {
    size_t nargs = place;
    pid_t pid;

    if ( nargs == 0 ) return;
    if ( !strcmp( args[0], "exit" ) ) exit(0);
    pid = fork();
    if ( pid ) {
        pid = wait( return_status );
    } else {
        if ( access( args[ 0 ], X_OK ) ){
            if( execvp( args[ 0 ], args ) ) {
                puts( strerror( errno ) );
                exit( 127 );
            }
        }else{
            puts( strerror( errno ) );
            exit( 127 );
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for ( i ; i < place + 1; i++)
        args[ i ] = NULL;
    place = 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    char line[MAXLINE+1];                       /* an input line */
    int c;                                      /* a single input char or EOF */
    int n;                                      /* line length */
    char *token;                                /* pointer to an input token */

    for(;;) {                                   /* repeat until end of file */ 
        write( 1, "#>", 2 );

        if (fgets(line,MAXLINE,stdin) == NULL)  /* end of file? */
            exit(0);

        n = strlen(line);                       /* get length of line */

        if (n == 0)                             /* if line is empty */
            continue;

        if (line[n-1] != '\n') {                /* does input end with '\n' ? */
            fprintf(stderr,"Line too long.\n"); /* no, so line is too long. */

            /*--------------------------------------------*/
            /* Read and ignore input through end of line. */
            /*--------------------------------------------*/
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
                if (c == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected end of file\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        write( 1, line, strlen( line ) );
        line[n-1] = '\0';                      /* remove the end of line */
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /* Identify and process each token (i.e. sequence of non-blank */
        /* characters delimited by whitespace). For "ordinary" tokens  */
        /* (i.e. "words") we just display them. For the ||, &&, and ;  */
        /* items we display them with a textual explanation.           */
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
        token = strtok(line," \t");
        while (token != NULL ) {
            insert( token );
            if (!strcmp(token,"&&")){
                place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;
                create();
                if( return_status == -1)
                    write( 1, "Wait failed.\n", 12 );
                if( return_status & 0xff ){
                    int i = 0;
                    for( i; i < place; i++)
                        args[ i ] = NULL;
                    place = 0;
                    while( strcmp( token, "||" ) || strcmp( token, ";" ) ) ;
                }
            }
            else if (!strcmp(token,"||")){
                place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;
                completed = 0;
                create();                
            }
            else if (!strcmp(token,";")){
                place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;
                create();
            }
            else{
            }
            token = strtok(NULL," \t");
        }
        create();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need some more information here... what does `create()` do? You're checking return_status, but never setting it... is `create()` supposed to set that? what is place initialized to? What is args[] declared as and initialized to?

Comment: Side note: Removed homework tag, it's obsolete, please don't use it just note it's homework in your post.

Comment: I ran this code with "ls && cat /home/me/some_file.txt" and I got the directory list and the file concatenated as output. On Linux did have to add #include <sys/wait.h> and change wait(return_code) to wait(&return_code).

Comment: the problem come up when the first program doesn't close with a return status of 1. As in, if I type false && echo one it still echos one.

Comment: Updated my answer below about &&.

Answer (score 1):

wait() takes an integer pointer, not integer. There should be a compiler warning for that. If not, I would recommend you use a warning flag.

```
#include <sys.wait.h>
wait(&return_code);
```

This check isn't correct as access() returns 0 on success. Doesn't seem like you can use access to check commands not in the current directory, unless they have given the full path to the executable or you are able to expand it. For example, "ls" would need to be expanded to "/bin/ls".

```
if ( access( args[ 0 ], X_OK ) ){
            if( execvp( args[ 0 ], args ) ) {
                puts( strerror( errno ) );
                exit( 127 );
            }
```

This check of the return_status is looking at the first byte but the program that was forked() or execvp() returns its status in the 2nd byte. The check for what it returned:

```
if( return_status & 0xff ){
```

should either be:

```
if ( WEXITSTATUS(return_status) != 0 ){
```

or

```
if ( (return_status & 0xff00) >> 8 ){
```

The if body:

```
      for( int i = 0; i < place; i++)
                        args[ i ] = NULL;
       place = 0;
       while( strcmp( token, "||" ) || strcmp( token, ";" ) ) ;
```

can be replaced by:

```
 break;
```

because you are doing the for loop and setting place to 0 inside create() and the while loop was infinite for me. Just breaking out of the enclosing while ends the command sequence and gets you back to reading another typed in command line.

```
  //if ( return_status == -1)
```

can use the wait() status macro:

```
  if ( ! WIFEXITED(return_status) )
```

Comment: i sort of understand but am having trouble implementing further. On our school system using return_status as an integer works so I was just going ahead with it that way. Should I change it? If so, how do you compare a pointer to an integer? Also, if I stop after the compare, how would I implement the code correctly to do an input like this: false && echo one ; echo two    In this assignment the ; operator is a consecutive operator that should allow the echo two argument to continue.

Comment: also, i get what you are saying about the access call but shouldn't that prevent the code from running as it is written? Then why does it still work?

Comment: access() returns non-zero on failure, so unless the command to be executed is sitting in the current directory, that if statement will be true and execute. Instead of giving the command "ls", give the full path, e.g. "/bin/ls" and you will see it fail because access() will return 0.

Comment: return_status cannot get a value from wait() unless passed as an address - &return_status. But after wait() returns you would look at return_status as just an int. Only wait() saw it as a pointer to an int. I will edit my answer to note some things I found that should make && work.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows what I mentioned in the other answer and works for "false && ls" and is updated to address further commands after an && fails.

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #define ARG_SIZE 1 << 16
    #define MAXLINE 100

    char *args[ARG_SIZE];
    int place = 0;
    int return_status;

    char message[200];

    void insert( char *token ){
        args[ place ] = token;
        place++;
    }

    void reset_args(void)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < place + 1; i++)
            args[ i ] = NULL;
        place = 0;
    }

    #define EXECVP_FAILED 127

    char last_command[200];

    void create() {
        size_t nargs = place;
        pid_t pid;

        if ( nargs == 0 ) return;
        if ( args[0] )
            strcpy(last_command,args[0]);
        else
           last_command[0] = '\0';
        if ( !strcmp( args[0], "exit" ) ) exit(0);
        pid = fork();
        if ( pid ) {
            pid = wait( &return_status );
        } else {
            if( execvp( args[ 0 ], args ) ) 
            {
               puts( strerror( errno ) );
               exit( EXECVP_FAILED );
            }
        }
        reset_args();
    }

    int main( void ){

       char line[MAXLINE+1];                       /* an input line */
       int c;                                      /* a single input char or EOF */
       int n;                                      /* line length */
       char *token;                                /* pointer to an input token */
       enum states { NORMAL, AND_CMD_FAILED };
       enum states state  = NORMAL;
       for(;;) {                                   /* repeat until end of file */ 
          state = NORMAL;
          write( 1, "#>", 2 );

          if (fgets(line,MAXLINE,stdin) == NULL)  /* end of file? */
             exit(0);

          n = strlen(line);                       /* get length of line */

          if (n == 0)                             /* if line is empty */
             continue;

          if (line[n-1] != '\n') {                /* does input end with '\n' ? */
             fprintf(stderr,"Line too long.\n"); /* no, so line is too long. */

             /*--------------------------------------------*/
             /* Read and ignore input through end of line. */
             /*--------------------------------------------*/
             while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
                if (c == EOF) {
                   fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected end of file\n");
                   exit(1);
                }
             }
             continue;
          }

          write( 1, line, strlen( line ) );
          line[n-1] = '\0';                      /* remove the end of line */
          /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
          /* Identify and process each token (i.e. sequence of non-blank */
          /* characters delimited by whitespace). For "ordinary" tokens  */
          /* (i.e. "words") we just display them. For the ||, &&, and ;  */
          /* items we display them with a textual explanation.           */
          /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
          token = strtok(line," \t");
          while (token != NULL ) {
             insert( token );
             if (!strcmp(token,"&&")){
                    place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;                      
                            if ( state == NORMAL )
                               create();
                            else
                               reset_args();

                if ( ! (WIFEXITED(return_status) ) || ( WEXITSTATUS(return_status)  ) )
                {
                   // command did not execute successfully
                   if ( ! WIFEXITED(return_status) )
                   {
                      sprintf(message,"Wait failed for %s\n",last_command);
                      write( 1, message, strlen(message) );
                   }
                   else if ( WEXITSTATUS(return_status) == EXECVP_FAILED )
                   {
                      sprintf(message,"execvp failed for %s\n",last_command);
                      write( 1, message, strlen(message) );
                   }
                   else  if ( WEXITSTATUS(return_status) != 0 ) {
                      sprintf(message,"%s command failed - exit status %d\n",
                              last_command,WEXITSTATUS(return_status));
                      write( 1, message, strlen(message) );
                   }
                   // bypass next command(s) up to || or ; delimiters
                   state = AND_CMD_FAILED;
                }
             }
             else if (!strcmp(token,"||")){
                place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;
                //completed = 0;
                if ( state == NORMAL )
                   create();
                else
                   reset_args();
                state = NORMAL;         
             }
             else if (!strcmp(token,";")){
                place--;
                args[ place ] = NULL;
                if ( state == NORMAL )
                   create();
                else
                   reset_args();
                state = NORMAL;
             }
             else{
             }
             token = strtok(NULL," \t");
          }
          if ( state == NORMAL )
             create();
          else
             reset_args();
       }
       return 0;
  }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the break exits the loop and therefore doesn't continue through the tokens. I tried false && echo one ; echo two and it didn't print two.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was only thinking about two commands separated by &&. I updated the code above. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I think I would also need to add a check for status to the beginning of the && comparison to check for false && ls && ls, right?

Comment: Adding the check in the && section seems to work. But when I do the same type of thing with the || operator I end up never executing any command.

Comment: Yes, to your first question. If you check check return_status in || and the command fails what do you set the state to? It should not be set to AND_CMD_FAILED. There could be an additional state OR_CMD_FAILED, but then the if surrounding create() needs to be modified to look for something besides == NORMAL since, as I understand it, an OR command can fail and the other side of the || should execute.